# Why doesn't Chrome see my CSS files in it's Coverage tab on my local development environment?

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-7, google-chrome-devtools

I've got a vagrant environment where I do some Drupal 7 development and I wanted to remove some unused CSS. So, I hit the record button and started loading pages. JavaScript files were picked up fine. And so were some external CSS files. But, it would not find any CSS.

I thought perhaps it was because of Drupal 7's practice of adding a query string to the end of its CSS and JS files, so I stopped Drupal from doing that. But still, it's not finding the CSS files. Any ideas why it wouldn't?

Comment: clear cache , and check aggregation configuration

Comment: no good :( cache is off on my development site anyway. aggregation is also turned off. I do compile my css from scss into one large css file and then turn on a source mapper to debug on dev, might that have something to do with it 

Comment: How about trying that in some other browser?

Comment: What other browser tests coverage?

Comment: I have no idea how Drupal works, but have you checked the box to include Content Scripts in the coverage tab?

Comment: That did it. Thanks Scott Beeson

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 7 uses `@import` rule to include css files. It was workaround for old IE browsers, which didn't allow to include more than 31 linked stylesheets. It looks like Google Chrome Coverage tool doesn't work properly with @import-ed stylesheets.

But there is a Drupal module [Link CSS](https://www.drupal.org/project/link_css). It allows to include css using `<link>` tag instead `@import`. So, if you install and enable it, Coverage tool will work as expected at your Drupal 7 site.